# WordPress database error MySQL server (Innodb Database Type) has gone away

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql 5.1.16 and word press ver 3.3.1

> WordPress database error MySQL server has gone away for query SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms as t WHERE t.name = 'quotes-news' made by shutdown_action_hook, do_action, call_user_func_array, autoblogged-> ab_shutdownIntercept, autoblogged->ab_processFeeds, autoblogged->ab_itemAddPost, wp_set_object_terms, wp_insert_term, term_exists

Anyone know what causing this?  it keeps shows in my error_log

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the php file "wp-db.php" (in the "wp-include/" folder of your Wordpress installation) and add

```
 $this->query("set session wait_timeout=600");
```

somewhere in the "___construct" method (around line 535), after the

```
if (!$this->dbh)
```

statement.

More info on this fix [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130310062853/http://thesocialmediaguide.com/wordpress-blog/solution-for-wordpress-database-error-mysql-server-has-gone-away-for-query) <--

And just in case: 
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Hope this helps.
(Source: Google).

Comment: The linked site seems to have disappeared. WayBackMachine has a copy here: https://web.archive.org/web/20130310062853/http://thesocialmediaguide.com/wordpress-blog/solution-for-wordpress-database-error-mysql-server-has-gone-away-for-query

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this is it's taking too long to execute the MySQL query. As well as Proreborn's workaround above, another possible fix is to speed up the database somehow. In my case, optimizing the tables in PHPMyAdmin was enough to stop this error.

Source: http://robsnotebook.com/wordpress-mysql-gone-away#comment-95722